# Can someone explain why I have to instantiate subclass?

Tags: java

Why do you have to instantiate subclass() in the mymethod() ? I thought that we only need to make objects in the main() method.(which is done here too) Why do we have to do it twice? Is there a special property of inheritance here?

```
class Super_class {
   int num = 20;

   // display method of superclass
   public void display() {
      System.out.println("This is the display method of superclass");
   }
}

public class Sub_class extends Super_class {
   int num = 10;

   // display method of sub class
   public void display() {
      System.out.println("This is the display method of subclass");
   }

   public void my_method() {
      // Instantiating subclass - why do you have to do this?
      Sub_class sub = new Sub_class();

      // Invoking the display() method of sub class
      sub.display();

      // Invoking the display() method of superclass
      super.display();

      // printing the value of variable num of subclass
      System.out.println("value of the variable named num in sub class:"+ sub.num);

      // printing the value of variable num of superclass
      System.out.println("value of the variable named num in super class:"+ super.num);
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Sub_class obj = new Sub_class();
      obj.my_method();
   }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do that.  Why do you think you need to?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to, but that said, in most applications you create `new` objects all over the place whenever you need them.

Comment: Your theory that you only make objects in the `main()` method is baseless.

Comment: @user207421 so when do you have to make objects? or what is the right theory

Comment: @Isabel You make objects whenever you decide that you need new objects. It can be in main() or in other methods. There is no rule that you can only create objects in main().

Comment: Incidentally, it is not normal Java coding style to have words separated by underscores like this, in either class names or method names.  This is probably not a habit that you want to develop, since you will have to unlearn it later. Names like "MyClass" or "myMethod" would be more normal. I suggest that you take a look at a style guide such as [this one](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) to get an idea of what Java code usually looks like.

Comment: @Some Guy I got the code from some online website. Doesn’t that mean the website is not reliable?

Comment: If this is the type of code that is appearing on that website, I wouldn't trust it very much. It uses strange coding conventions and seems to be creating objects like 'sub' for no obvious reason. This suggests that the author of the code is not very familiar with Java. I would suggest instead that you start with the official [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) which will give you some basis by which to evaluate other teaching sites.

Comment: @Some Guy I want to learn java swing and so I search on websites online. Do you mind recommending me websites that are good?

Comment: @Isabel The Java Tutorials has a section on Swing [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html). I suggest starting with that. Before you start to learn Swing, though, I suggest making sure you have a solid understanding of the Java language itself, by reading at least the relevant tutorial sections [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html).

Comment: @SomeGuy so to learn how to code is: 1) build stuff like do assignments 2) ask stackoverflow 3) learn from mistakes 3) make more stuff using code ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do these things you've done on the subclass. When you're inside the class you don't need to instantiate it to call its attribute and methods: you can do it directly, so doing like this is enough:

```
  public void my_method() {

  // Invoking the display() method of sub class
  display();

  // Invoking the display() method of superclass
  super.display();

  // printing the value of variable num of subclass
  System.out.println("value of the variable named num in sub class:"+ num);

  // printing the value of variable num of superclass
  System.out.println("value of the variable named num in super class:"+ super.num);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to do that, you can call the display method of the sub class with the **this** keyword or even without that inside my_method() you do not need object of sub class.

But what you have done here simply created a new object inside my_method(), so basically your my_method() method and display() methods are getting called by different object.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to instantiate a new object, and in fact, I would consider that a bad coding practice.  What you need to do is reference the current object using the `this` keyword, or just calling `display();`, which implicitly means `this.display();`.  If you create a new object, if there are any instance variables set, they would reset to their default values because the instance you are referencing is not the same instance the method was called on, so you could get unexpected behavior.